# Moving, clickable, rectangle animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I've searched and searched, but couldn't find what I was looking for...
There are many ways to animate in android and being a newbie I do not know which solution to choose for my app.
Here's what I want to do:

1. It's an animation of rectangles moving slowly (takes ~10 min to cross the screen) from top to bottom through the screen.
2. Each and every one of the rectangles is clickable, through some listener, and does something.
3. Two or three buttons at the bottom of the screen (which I already created as floating action buttons) do not move and float "on top", i.e. the moving rectangles pass underneath them as they move down the screen.
4. The animation can be stopped and then resumes by the action buttons mentioned above.
5. Newly appearing rectangles appear on top as they " emerge" slowly from the top of the screen, i.e. when part of them is still outside, as they reveal themself by moving down.
6. I want this to be simple and robust.

How should I implement this, and please explain why...
As a loop?
A separate thread? Of so how?
I would like to understand the rationale behind every approach...
Thanks,
Julius

Comment: if it takes 10 minutes or so then `Animators` are not the right choice, see `Handler` and how to send `Messages` or post `Runnables` and no: no loops, no threads, those are bad guys....

Comment: I'm busy figuring out how the Handler works and how to use it (I'm used to "stone age" programming with loops etc (-; )

Comment: so like dinosaurs, either you have to die or to change completely your programming horizons... ;-)

Comment: for a starting point create a `handler = new Handler`, override its `handleMessage` method add some `Log.d` inside and call `handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 3000)`